# Return multiple exchange rates from one call using WebServiceX.net

Tags: c#, web-services

I use this URL to get a conversion rate from Euros to GBP:
http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=EUR&ToCurrency=GBP

I also need to convert US dollars and Australian dollars too.  Instead of calling the web service multiple times, I was wondering if there was a way to return all exchange rates at once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesnt appear to support batch currency downloads.

You'd have to pull them one at a time.

I'd suggest implementing a cache system in front of that to only pull what you need at the time, since their API will probably rate limit you.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I'd just keep all the rates in a text file in my App_Data folder and update them daily.